# tools for extracting code metric directly from SVN/CVS/Git repositories

Tags: metrics

Today is the second day that i am searching in the internet for a tool that can extract various kinds of metrics directly from repositories. i want something like this

toolname [SVN/CVS/Git repository address]

do you know anything useful and complete ?

Thankyou.

Comment: It might be easier to solve your problem in two steps:  export SVN/etc to a set of directories, then run a conventional file-oriented tool.   This is pretty trivial to do as a command script.

Comment: would you please tell me name of some of these tool that i can use ?

Comment: One issue is there are a lot of different metrics, and a lot of different tool building organizations. Generally you have to search for the specific metrics measurements you want, by language. But here's a start: http://www.arisa.se/files/LLL-08.pdf.  You can check my bio for a wide variety of such tools from my company if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are a huge variety of metrics of different types, that apply to different kinds of programming artifacts.  You're unlikely to find a tool that handles either kind variety in a really broad sense.

If you are willing to settle for some common metrics (SLOC, CommentCount, Cyclomatic Complexity, Halstead metrics, etc.), our [Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) can provide them for a relatively wide range of common computer languages.  Bear with me a moment :-}

Normally the SearchEngine is used to provide fast, interactive interface for searching across large source code bases (the kind often found in SVN/CVS/Git ...) with multiple computer languages.   It provides a fast search by indexing all the source code files, using language-specific processors to handle each type of file.  These processors identify the langauge elements of each computer langauge accurately (identifiers, numbers, strings, whitespace, comments, operators, ...), and enable the search engine to find only code constructs that are not bogus and are layout independent, so it maximizes hits while minimizing false positives.  The Search Engine has processors for a wide (ahem) range of languages.

As a side effect of indexing the code, the SearchEngine just so happens to compute these common metrics at the file level (using the langauge-specific details) into an XML file, than can be [rendered easily into an HTML report](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine/SearchEngineMetricsExample.html) if you like.  This means you can have these common metrics for multiple languages rather easily.   The SearchEngine has a module to recognize "psuedo-code", too, which is relatively robust, and can pick up much of the code in langauges the SearchEngine for which it otherwise does not have a specific processor.

Answer (score 0):

I usualy make use of [Ohloh.net](http://www.ohloh.net) which has some tools to extract some basic statistics from your git/mercurial/bazaar/svn repositories. The friendly fellas at Ohloh have even made some of their source publicly available. I haven't had the need to know my codebase's metrics at command, but if you do Ohloh might not be the ultimate metrics aggregation tool for you as they measure your codebase's metrics at intervals. It was good enough for me ;). Anyways... Ohloh is by far the easiest way to get metrics for open-source-ish projects (your code needs to reside somewhere where the Ohloh service can access it).

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://metricsgrimoire.github.io/

That has a tool called cvsanaly which can extract metrics from code repostories